# Kotlin Navigation Drawer using Navigation Component with RecyclerView for Menu

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, drawerlayout, android-navigationview

I am having an issue with my navigation drawer using the navigation component. I customized my Drawer Layout and added Custom Navigation View with Recycler View. I generated my custom layout menu in Grid View which is inside NavigationView.

The issue is that when I navigate by clicking on any item in grid view it navigates and works fine but when I click again to navigate to another fragment it gives an error. Navigation works fine if I navigate from the main screen to another fragment but not work if I navigate from fragment to fragment.

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photoContainer"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:columnWidth="74dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                drawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val width = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels
        val params = nav_view.layoutParams as DrawerLayout.LayoutParams
        params.width = width
        nav_view.layoutParams = params
        val menus = arrayOf("Photo", "Video")
        val icon = intArrayOf(
                R.drawable.ic_menu_photo,
                R.drawable.ic_menu_video)
        val iconSelected = intArrayOf(
                R.drawable.ic_menu_photo,
                R.drawable.ic_menu_video)
menuData = ArrayList<MenuNavigationModel>()
        for (i in menus.indices) {
            val menu = MenuNavigationModel()
            menu.menuName = menus[i]
            menu.menuIcon = icon[i]
            menuData!!.add(menu)
        }
        gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridview) as GridView
        adapter = MenuNavigationAdapter(this, menuData!!)
        gridView!!.adapter = adapter

gridView!!.onItemClickListener = OnItemClickListener { parent, v, i, id ->
            try {
                if(i === 0)
                    findNavController(R.id.main_nav_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_photoFragment)

                if(i === 1)
                    findNavController(R.id.main_nav_fragment).navigate(R.id.homeFragment_to_videoFragment)
            }catch (e: Exception){
                Toast.makeText(this, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.e("Error_Nav", e.message.toString())
            }
            val drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) as DrawerLayout
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    }
```

It returns me this error: Navigation action/destination cannot be found from the current destination Destination
Yes, I know it's saying that the action is not provided in navigation but how do I tell my gridview to dynamically handle this like menu items. Kindly guide whats the better way of doing this.

Comment: You need to add action in navigation graph. Like consider you're at FragA and you want to navigate to FragB then you need to add action(with destination of FragB) in FragA in navigation graph

Comment: Then how will my gridview know its on which fragment and execute particular action? Isn't make it more complicated

Comment: So you want to navigate to FragA when you click grid item-1, navigate to FragB when you click grid item-2 and so on. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, i want to navigate as it is working with menu items

Comment: You can add Type to identify which fragment you want to load. Like If grid item Type = Chat then load FragA, If grid item Type =  Task then load FragB, and so on. This way you can archive what you're asking

Comment: Can give any example?